# Flex horizontal layout that wraps to the next line?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

Is there a Flex layout class that wraps to the next line and does not size all the items the same size?

I've tried using TileLayout but the problem with that is that all the items are sized to the largest item. I want to set the gap between each to be consistent. Basically a variableColumnWidth type of feature.

```
<s:List id="exampleList" 
        selectedIndex="0"
        width="100%"
        dataProvider="{examplesCollection}" 
        change="exampleList_changeHandler(event)"
        height="250"
        >
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0" />

    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

I'm using Apache Flex 4.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the quickest way would be to implement an item renderer, like this [example](http://flexlayouts.org/2010/08/flowlayout/). The other option is to implement your own layout which you can adapt to what you need, for this you need to understand very well how layouts work.

Comment: Actually, the layout I'm looking for is on the same site. Thank you